# Create nested tuples from list of family members

Tags: python

My code:

```
class Person:

def __init__(self, name = None, mother = None, father = None, born = None, died = None):
    self.name = name
    self.mother = mother
    self.father = father
    self.born = born
    self.died = died

def __str__(self):
    if self.died == None:
        return f'{self.name} {self.born}- '
    else:
        return f'{self.name} {self.born}-{self.died}'
    

def ancestor(self):
    if self.mother and self.father is not None:
        return (str(self), (self.ancestor(self.mother), self.ancestor(self.father)))
    else: 
        if (self.mother is None) and (self.father is not None):
            return (str(self), (self.ancestor(self.father)))
        elif (self.father is None) and (self.mother is not None):
            return (str(self), (self.ancestor(self.mother)))
        elif self.mother and self.father is None:
            return (str(self))
    
class AnnotatedPerson(Person):
    def __init__(self, name = None, mother = None, father = None, born = None, died = None, note = None):
        self.note = note
        super().__init__(name, mother, father, born, died=None)
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.died == None:
            return f'{self.name} {self.born}- [{self.note}]'
        else:
            return f'{self.name} {self.born}-{self.died} [{self.note}]'
```

My goal is for ancestor() to create a nested tuple that shows how closely they are related (like a family tree) so that these people would create the following tuple:

```
sarah = Person("Sarah", None, None, 1817, 1898)
chris = Person("Chris", None, None, 1818, 1906)
amanda = AnnotatedPerson("Amanda", None, None, 1851, 1926, "was a doctor")
fred = Person("Fred", sarah, chris, 1870, 1947)
walter = Person("Walter", amanda, fred, 1870, 1947)
emma = AnnotatedPerson("Emma", None, None, 1910, 2000, "was a vet")
john = Person("John", None, walter, 1899, 1972)
mary = AnnotatedPerson("Mary", emma, john, 1940, note="is an actress") 

('Mary 1940- [is an actress]', ('John 1899-1972', ('Walter 1870-1947', ('Fred 1870-1947', ('Chris 1818-1906'), ('Sarah 1817-1898')), ('Amanda 1851-1926 [was a doctor]'))), ('Emma 1910-2000 [was a vet]'))
```

My problem is that i can't figure out a solution for ancestor() to produce a tuple. Currently it's not working at all so i assume i'm doing something completely wrong here.

Would really appreciate some pointers or just to know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: OT: you might have a bug in `ancestor():` - both following statements will be evaluated equally in case `mother` is non-empty and `father` is empty: `elif (self.father is None) and (self.mother is not None)` and `elif self.mother and self.father is None:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the base case of your `ancestor` function be a check if the person object passed to it is `None`. That way, no extraneous logic has to be used when forming the tuple itself:

```
def ancestor(person):
   if person is None:
      return ()
   return tuple(filter(None, (str(person), ancestor(person.father), ancestor(person.mother))))

print(ancestor(mary))
```

Output:

```
('Mary 1940- [is an actress]', ('John 1899-1972', ('Walter 1870-1947', ('Fred 1870-1947', ('Chris 1818-1906',), ('Sarah 1817-1898',)), ('Amanda 1851- [was a doctor]',))), ('Emma 1910- [was a vet]',))
```

Edit: if `ancestor` is a method of `Person`, the logic can become even simpler when using `getattr`:

```
class Person:
    ...
    def ancestor(self):
       return tuple(filter(None, (str(self), 
                getattr(self.father, 'ancestor', lambda :None)(), 
                getattr(self.mother, 'ancestor', lambda :None)()
       )))

print(mary.ancestor())
```